# Linear Transformation with different dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Let $f$ be a linear map that maps $V$ to $W$, such that $\dim W < \dim V$.

a) Show that exists some $v \in V$,$v\neq0$, such that $f(v) = 0$.

b) If $B$ is a some arbitrary base for $V$, is there always some vector $v$ such thjat $f(v) = 0$? Prove it or give a counter-example.

My answer:

$B_v$ is a basis for $V$ and $B_w$ is a basis for $W$:
$$
B_v = \left\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\right\}\\
B_w = \left\{f(v_1),f(v_2),...,f(v_m)\right\}\\
$$

but $\dim W < \dim V$, so there will always exists some $v \in V$ such that $f(v) = 0$.

Is my approach good enough to answer both letters? If not, what would be your answer?!

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which maps $(x,y)$ to $(x,y,0)$. Then there exists no nonzero $v$ with $f(v)=0$. I think you should change the order.

Comment: sorry, it was $\dim W < \dim V$

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\mbox{Im}(f)$ and $K=\mbox{Ker}(f)$. Using the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim V-\dim K=\dim U$. Since $U$ is a subspace of $W$, we know that $\dim U \leq \dim W$, so $\dim V-\dim K\leq \dim W < \dim V$. Thus $\dim K$ is greater than $0$ which implies there exists a nonzero element $v\in V$ with $f(v)=0$.

However, the second claim is false since $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f(x,y,z)=(x,y)$ does not contain any basis element in its kernel if you take the basis as $\{ v_1=(1,0,0), v_2=(1,1,0), v_3=(1,1,1)\}$. As you may notice $f(v_2)=f(v_3)$ and that explains why your argument does not work.

Comment: $\{ v_1=(1,0,0), v_2=(1,1,0), v_3=(1,1,1)\}$ is not a basis, since $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$... I still think that my argument works mate.

Comment: But your first explanation with rank-nullity theorem is perfect! <3

Comment: $v_1+v_2 = (2,1,0)$ and you can't get $v_3$ using $v_1$ and $v_2$ since both of them are on the $XY$ plane whereas $v_3$ has a $Z$ component.  Thanks btw :)

Comment: oooh ur right! Sorry for that. So my answer is ok for letter a, but there will exists some counter example to show that we can have a linear map that changes dimensions without any vector in its kernel. correct?!

Comment: Your argument is fine for a since it shows that there exist $v_i,v_j$ in $B_V$ with $f(v_i)=f(v_j)$ which implies $f(v_i-v_j)=0$. But it is possible for a linear map has a nonzero kernel but the space has a basis which does not intersect with the kernel.

Comment: yeah, the answer depends on ur basis, and since we want a general answer, my argument does not guarantee the correct answer to B. Thank you mate!